# Multiclass classification on imbalanced dataset : Accuracy or micro F1 or macro F1

Tags: multiclass-classification, accuracy

I have a multiclass classification problem. Further, an instance can be assigned to exactly one class. My dataset is highly imbalanced. I know that accuracy is not a good metric to use in this case because one can simply predict the high frequent class and get a good score. I understand that [micro F1 is better than macro F1 for multiclass classification problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24051/58385) but it turns out that [the micro F1 score is the same as accuracy score](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42105228/530399). So, the whole idea of looking into alternative metric (i.e. micro F1) instead of accuracy has gone full circle.

Should I be using macro F1 instead?

Comment: Without hesitating, especially in the cases you are interested in the positive class (usually in the minority class also).

Comment: AUROC is probably the most used along with f1 (micro or macro).

Answer (score 3):

There are two not so widely known in the data science community metrics that work well for imbalanced data and can be used for multi-class data: Cohen's kappa and Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC).

Cohen's kappa is a statistic that was designed to measure inter-annotator agreement, but it can be used to measure agreement between the ground truth and a prediction. There are number of explanations online e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) or [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/cohens-kappa-statistic/) and it is implemented in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.html).

MMC was initially designed for a binary classification but then generalized for multi-class data. There are also multiple online sources for MCC, e.g.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) and [here](https://lettier.github.io/posts/2016-08-05-matthews-correlation-coefficient.html), and it is implemented in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html).

Hope this helps.