# Choice of f1 score for highly imbalanced dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, model-evaluations, class-imbalance, metric

I am confused whether to use f1 score with 'micro' average or 'macro' average for better evaluation.
Given my dataset is highly imbalanced(600:100000)

Answer (score 1):

To summarise this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin),

Macro calculates and F1 score for each class then averages them.

Micro calculates the recall/precision for each class, averages them then calculates the F1 score.

Micro average is preferable in a multi class situation where one class heavily outweighs the others.