# What is the formula to calculate the precision, recall, f-measure with macro, micro, none for multi-label classification in sklearn metrics?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am working in the problem of multi-label classification tasks. But I would not able to understand the formula for calculating the precision, recall, and f-measure with macro, micro, and none. Moreover, I understood the formula to calculate these metrics for samples. Even, I am also familiar with the example-based, label-based, and rank-based metrics.

For instance,

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import hamming_loss, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score 
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
y_true = np.array([[0, 1, 1 ],
                   [1, 0, 1 ],
                   [1, 0, 0 ],
                   [1, 1, 1 ]])

y_pred = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1]])


conf_mat=multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
print("Confusion_matrix_Train\n", conf_mat)
```

Confusion matrix output:

```
 [[[1 0]
  [1 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [0 2]]

 [[1 0]
  [1 2]]]
```

Macro score

```
print("precision_score:", precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
print("recall_score:", recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
print("f1_score:", f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
```

Macro score output:

```
precision_score: 0.8888888888888888
recall_score: 0.7777777777777777
f1_score: 0.8000000000000002
```

Micro score

```
print("precision_score:", precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
print("recall_score:", recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
print("f1_score:", f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
```

Micro score output:

```
precision_score: 0.8571428571428571
recall_score: 0.75
f1_score: 0.7999999999999999
```

Weighted score

```
print("precision_score:", precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted'))
print("recall_score:", recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted'))
print("f1_score:", f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted'))
```

Weighted score output:

```
precision_score: 0.9166666666666666
recall_score: 0.75
f1_score: 0.8
```

Samples score

```
print("precision_score:", precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='samples'))
print("recall_score:", recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='samples'))
print("f1_score:", f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='samples'))
```

Samples score output:

```
precision_score: 0.75
recall_score: 0.75
f1_score: 0.75
```

None score

```
print("precision_score:", precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None))
print("recall_score:", recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None))
print("f1_score:", f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None))
```

None score output:

```
precision_score: [1.         0.66666667 1.        ]
recall_score: [0.66666667 1.         0.66666667]
f1_score: [0.8 0.8 0.8]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, the scoring metrics you are looking at are defined as following (see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)):

$$precision = \frac{TP}{TP+FP}$$
$$recall= \frac{TP}{TP+FN}$$
$$F1 = \frac{2 \times precision \times recall}{precision + recall}$$

For the multi-class case scikit learn offers the following parameterizations (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) for example):

> **'micro'**:
>   Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.
>
> **'macro'**:
>   Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.
>
> **'weighted':**
>   Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall.
>
> **'samples':**
>   Calculate metrics for each instance, and find their average (only meaningful for multilabel classification where this differs from accuracy_score).

And `none` does the following:

> If `None`, the scores for each class are returned.

**TLDR:** "micro" calculates the overall metric, "macro" derives an average assigning each class an equal weight and "weighted" calculates an average assigning each class a weight based on the number of ocurences (its support).

---

Accordingly, the calculations in your example go like this:

**Macro**

$$precision_{macro} = \sum_{classes} \frac{precision\text{ }of \text{ }class}{number\text{ }of\text{ }classes} = \frac{(2/2) + (2/3) + (2/2)}{3} \approx 0.89$$

$$recall_{macro} = \sum_{classes} \frac{recall\text{ }of \text{ }class}{number\text{ }of\text{ }classes} = \frac{(2/3) + (2/2) + (2/3)}{3} \approx 0.78$$

$$F1_{macro}= \ \sum_{classes} \frac{F1\text{ }of \text{ }class}{number\text{ }of\text{ }classes} = \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2 \times (2/2) \times (2/3)}{(2/2) + (2/3)} + \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2 \times (2/3) \times (2/2)}{(2/3) + (2/3)} + \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2 \times (2/2) \times (2/3)}{(2/2) + (2/3)} \approx 0.80$$

Note that macro means that all classes have the same weight, i.e. $\frac{1}{3}$ in your example. That is where the $\times \frac{1}{3}$ to calculate the F1 score comes from.

---

**Micro**

$$precision_{micro} = \frac{\sum_{classes} TP\text{ }of \text{ }class}{\sum_{classes} TP\text{ }of\text{ }class + FP\text{ }of\text{ }class } = \frac{2+2+2}{2+3+2} \approx 0.86$$

$$recall_{micro} = \frac{\sum_{classes} TP\text{ }of \text{ }class}{\sum_{classes} TP\text{ }of\text{ }class+FN\text{ }of\text{ }class} = \frac{2+2+2}{3+2+3} = 0.75$$

$$F1_{micro}= 2\times \frac{recall_{micro} \times precision_{micro}}{recall_{micro} + precision_{micro}} \approx 0.8$$

---

**Weighted**
$$precision_{weighted} = \sum_{classes}{weight\text{ }of \text{ }class \times precision\text{ }of\text{ }class} = \frac{3}{8}\times\frac{2}{2} + \frac{2}{8}\times\frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{2} \approx 0.92$$

$$recall_{weighted} = \sum_{classes}{weight\text{ }of \text{ }class \times recall\text{ }of\text{ }class} = \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{8}\times\frac{2}{2} + \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{3} = 0.75$$

$$F1_{weighted} = \sum_{classes}{weight\text{ }of \text{ }class \times F1\text{ }of\text{ }class} = \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2 \times (2/2) \times (2/3)}{(2/2) + (2/3)} + \frac{2}{8} \times \frac{2 \times (2/3) \times (2/2)}{(2/3) + (2/3)} + \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2 \times (2/2) \times (2/3)}{(2/2) + (2/3)} = 0.8$$

---

**None**

$precision_{class 1} = \frac{2}{2} = 1.0$

$precision_{class 2} = \frac{2}{2+1} \approx 0.67$

$precision_{class 3} = \frac{2}{2} = 1.0$

$recall_{class 1} = \frac{2}{2+1}  \approx 0.67$

$recall_{class 2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1.0$

$recall_{class 3} = \frac{2}{2+1} \approx 0.67$

$F1_{class 1} =  \frac{2 \times 1 \times \frac{2}{3}}{1 + \frac{2}{3}} = 0.8$

$F1_{class 2} =  \frac{2  \times \frac{2}{3}\times 1}{\frac{2}{3} + 1} = 0.8$

$F1_{class 3} =  \frac{2 \times 1 \times \frac{2}{3}}{1 + \frac{2}{3}} = 0.8$

---

**Samples**

$$Precision_{samples}= \frac{1}{Number\, of\, examples} \sum_{examples} \frac{TP\,of\,example}{TP\,of\,example + FP\,of\,example} = \frac{1}{4}[\frac{2}{2}+\frac{0}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{3}{3}] = 0.75$$

$$Recall_{samples}= \frac{1}{Number\, of\, examples} \sum_{examples} \frac{TP\,of \,example}{TP\,of\,example + FN\,of\,example} = \frac{1}{4}[\frac{2}{2}+\frac{0}{2}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{3}{3}] = 0.75$$

$$F1_{samples}= 2\times \frac{recall_{samples} \times precision_{samples}}{recall_{samples} + precision_{samples}} = 0.75$$

Comment: Good job. I think there is a little change in the formula of recall micro. Am i right?

Comment: @AshokKumarJayaraman you are right! I have edited it accordingly. Moreover, I have edited the formula for $precision_{micro}$ since the sums need to go into the denominator and numerator. Calculations remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for writing this up. Just be aware there is a typo in the F1_macro formula: the second term should have a different denominator, namely (1/3) x (numerator is OK)/(2/3 + 2/2). In turn, all three terms are the same and the result is then _exactly_ 0.8. A sanity check: F1 of each class is 0.8, so the arithmetic average of three equal values must be 0.8 too.

Comment: Now I see the same typo occurs in F1_weighted: again, the second term should have a different denominator.

Comment: And my third comment goes to F1_micro: if you used Precision_micro = 6/7 (i.e. not rounded to 0.86), you would get F1_micro = 0.8 exactly (i.e. not only approximately). It is a simple operation with fractions. Ironically, the sklearn result above does the rounding too.

Answer (score 0):

```
A macro-average will compute the metric independently for each class and then take the average (hence treating all classes equally), whereas a micro-average will aggregate the contributions of all classes to compute the average metric.


In your case as per your confusion matrix,
 Class 1 TP = 1 FP = 0 
 Class 2 TP = 1 FP = 1
 Class 3 TP = 1 FP = 0

and the precision formula is given as TP/(TP + FP)

So precision 

Pa = 1 /( 1 + 0 ) = 1
pb = 1 /( 1 + 1) = 0.5
pc = 1 /(1 + 0 ) = 1

Precision with Macro is 
Pma = pa + pb + pc / 3  = 1 + 0.5 + 1 / 3 =  0.8333

Precision with Micro is 
Pmi = TPa + TPb + TPc / (TPa + FPa + TPb + FPb + TPc + FPc) =  1 + 1 + 1 / ( 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0) = 0.75

Please refer to the below link which very well described the difference between Marco and Micro.
```

[Micro Average vs Macro average Performance in a Multiclass classification setting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin)

https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-ii-the-f1-score-ebe8b2c2ca1