# Different definitions of Macro F1 score, which one is used in Scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, f1score

In this article [Macro F1 and Macro F1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.03347.pdf) two different definitions of the F1 used in the literature are demonstrated. 
The first F1 score is computed such as:

> F1 scores are computed for each class and then averaged via
>   arithmetic mean

The second such as:

> The harmonic mean is computed over the arithmetic means of precision
>   and recall

I was wondering which definition is actually implemented in Scikit-learn. 
From the docs I cannot derive which definition is used:

> Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This
>   does not take label imbalance into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variant is implemented:
$$F1_{macro}= \ \sum_{classes} \frac{F1\text{ }of \text{ }class}{number\text{ }of\text{ }classes}$$

You can find an example calculation in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68410/84891).

Sometimes the scikit learn documentation does not include all the details. In these cases it is often helpful to look into the source code which is linked on all help-sites. [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L1325) you can find some more details on the f1 score calculation.