# How do I calculate precision, recall, specificity, sensitivity manually?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have actual class labels and predicted class labels:

```
2 , 1
0 , 0
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
1 , 1
2 , 1
1 , 1
0 , 0
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
3 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
1 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
1 , 1
1 , 1
0 , 0
1 , 1
1 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
1 , 1
2 , 1
1 , 1
0 , 0
2 , 1
1 , 1
0 , 0
2 , 1
2 , 1
0 , 0
2 , 1
2 , 1
2 , 1
```

I am using a scikit-learn function to generate the confusion matrix and get the accuracy:

```
print(classification_report(actual_label, pred_res))
```

Which yields:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00         6
           1       1.00      0.28      0.43        36
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
           3       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

    accuracy                           0.38        42
   macro avg       0.50      0.32      0.36        42
weighted avg       1.00      0.38      0.52        4
```

Is there any other way to calculate the precision, recall, sensitivity, and specificity, without using the above function?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68410/84891) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. For example, you could use pandas to cross-tabulate the label values. Note that, judging by your output, the true labels are actually the second column in your table.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('labels.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['predicted', 'actual']

print(pd.crosstab(df.actual, df.predicted))
```

```
predicted  0   1   2  3
actual                 
0          6   0   0  0
1          0  10  25  1
```

From this table, you can calculate all the metrics by hand, according to their [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall). For example, the recall (a.k.a sensitivity) for the labels that are actually 1 is
$$ \frac{10}{10 + 25 + 1} \approx 0.28, $$
in agreement with the scikit-learn output.