# Difference between MAP@K for recommendations, MAP from Precision Recall Curves and Macro-Precision

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have been using the 3 metrics independently for a while now, but trying to figure out if they are actually 3 separate things (with similar-looking definitions/names) or there is some underlying connection between them.

**mAP** - Mean Average Precision is the average of the Precision-Recall curve over various thresholds. <sup>[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqXDdxF_Wuw&ab_channel=Roboflow)</sup> <sup>[2](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173)</sup>

**MAP@k** -
Mean (over all data points) of the AP@K (which is average precision for K predictions) <sup>[3](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276/handouts/EvaluationNew-handout-1-per.pdf)</sup> <sup>[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748792/understanding-precisionk-apk-mapk)</sup> <sup>[5](https://sdsawtelle.github.io/blog/output/mean-average-precision-MAP-for-recommender-systems.html)</sup>

**Macro-Precision** -
Un-weighted average of classwise-precision <sup>[6](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin)</sup> <sup>[7](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html)</sup>

It would be great to hear thoughts on how to reconcile these concepts. *Please do check the links for more details on what I am referring to since nomenclature might vary from place to place.*