# Can I use macro recall to check if my RF model is overfitting?

Tags: random-forest, class-imbalance, overfitting, precision-recall-curve

I have a dataset with 837377 observations (51% to train, 25% to validation and 24% to test) and 19 features.

I calculated the recall score using average macro for train, validation and test and obtained:

Train: 0.9981845060159042
Val: 0.7559011239753489
Test: 0.7325217067167821

Can I say my multiclass and imbalanced Random Forest model is overfitting by saying that **recall_train > recall_val** and **recall_train > recall_test**? Is recall the best metric to use in this case?

Comment: How many classes has your dataset? What is their distribution?

Comment: 11 Classes. For the train dataset - 0: 65295, 1: 870, 2: 469, 3: 1943, 4: 100725, ...

Comment: BTW, I am also using IoU (Intersection over Union) for this analysis. Maybe this is a better metric in this case.

Comment: I do not have practice with IoU, but I have learned that essentially is a fraction $\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}$ where $A$ and $B$ are, for example, geometrical objects (e.g., rectangles). Is this really what you want?

Comment: Yes, I saw that IoU can also be applied on my case. The equation is the following: IoU = true_positive/(true_positive+false_positive+false_negative).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the micro or macro F1 score for unbalanced problems like yours.

To understand the difference between micro versus macro metric, read this great [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24051/132904) (and follow-up comments).