# Multilabel metrics: micro vs. macro vs. weighted vs. samples?

Tags: model-evaluations, multilabel-classification, precision-recall-curve

I'm working on a multilabel classification problem; there are $N$ classes and each example can belong to $[0, N]$ of those classes. Below you can see the precision and recall computed using various averaging options with `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support`. The number in square brackets is the total area under the curve.

Intuitively, I understand the difference between `micro` and `macro`: if I have imbalanced classes, then the rarer classes will still contribute the equally as the more common classes. This is one reason why `macro` can do better than `micro`, which is if rarer classes that have good performance and are skewing results with heavier contribution they they normally would have.

However, what I don't understand is why `weighted` can do so much better than everything else - if anything, I would think that `weighted` should place somewhere in between `micro` and `macro`, as rarer classes will once again be weighted less ([other threads](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin) have suggested using `weighted` as a "stand in" for `micro`).

Finally, there's `samples`, which calculates statistics for per-example (instead of per-class), then takes the unweighted average across all examples. This is obviously the same as transposing the results so classes become examples and examples become classes, then taking the macro average. I am not sure when to use these at all.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

**In short: in multilabel classification, if `weighted` averaging of precision and recall gives much "better" results than `micro` and `macro`, what is this indicative of?**

[image]